# Potential near a charged cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

A non-conductive electrically charged cylinder of length $L$ and radius $R_o$ has a uniform charge distribution $q$.

What is the potential $V$ at the cap and bottom ($z=-L/2, z=+L/2$)? And at the surface $r=R_o$?

I've been searching this but I struggle with the relationship between *charge, potential and electrical field*.

Comment: Is the charge also on the caps? If this were in infinite cylinder, the calculation would be straight-forward using Gauss's law. With a finite length, you are looking at a complex tripel integral.

Comment: @R.W.Bird From what I understand there's charge on the caps, as the cylinder is uniformly charged. Why the triple integral? (this question derives from another one. I'm basically trying to determine some BC for a Laplace equation)

Comment: Question that this was inspired by: [Laplace's Equation and Boundary Condition Problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606362/157014).

Comment: @Gert Also note that in that question, the rod is "thin", meaning (I assume) that we're ignoring its radius. In which case we're not interested in the caps, but rather just near the surface $r = R_o$. And I suppose very close to the surface you could imagine the cylinder to be infinite, which would go like $\sim \ln(r/a)$, where $a$ is some reference point where the potential is taken to be zero.

Comment: @Philip I have purposefully *not*  assumed $P_r=0$. It would of course simplify things no end to do so. But I don't think it's in the *spirit* of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential is defined as $V(\vec{r_0})=\int\limits_{V} \frac{qdV}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \left|\vec{r_0}-\vec{r}\right|}$.

The point where the potential is to be evaluated is $\vec{r_0}=[ \ x_0 \ y_0 \ z_0 \  ] = [\ r_0 \ \phi_0 \ z_0 ]$. The former is in Certesian and the latter is in cylindrical coordinates.

The point where the volume element $dV$ is located is $\vec{r}=[\ x \ y \ z]=[\ r\ \phi\ z \ ]$.

$V(\vec{r})=\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2} \int\limits_{-R_0}^{R_0} \int\limits_{-\sqrt{R_0^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R_0^2-y^2}}\frac{qdxdydz}{4\pi\epsilon_0\sqrt{(x_0-x)^2+(y_0-y)^2+(z_0-z)^2}} = \int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{R_0}\frac{rqdrd\phi dz}{4\pi\epsilon_0\sqrt{\left|\vec{r_0}\right|^2+r^2-2(\vec{r_0}\cdot\vec{r})}}$.

It's a straightforward but laborious integral. I'd probably spend an entire day calculating that. But it is doable.

The cylindrical version contains a scalar product; I'd probably stick to Certesian in the end.

Comment: Wow. So it really is quite involved then! Thank you!